# How welcome are lay questions?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

I am no economist.  However, economy literally affects everybody.  Are lay questions welcome or is this site aimed only at academic research level questions and answers?

Comment: Welcome! The site is definitely aimed towards experts. However, well-thought out questions are welcome from everyone. I think we should write up some guidelines for asking high quality questions. I think I've seen some meta posts related to this.

Comment: I had the impression that this SE was also geared towards students of economics, which would give room to well-expressed but novel questions. Am I wrong here?

Comment: You might want to check this thread also http://meta.economics.stackexchange.com/questions/142/what-level-are-we-aiming-for-now-we-are-in-public-beta

Comment: Also, if you don't consider yourself an expert, consider not up-voting answers unless they are clearly backed up by references or the person demonstrates clear (think mathematical) rigor.

Comment: I think the strategy is to first attract experts and then, after attracting experts, answer more lay questions. I think we are still in the attract-the-experts stage, but I am happy to be corrected by others.